# concatenate string with variable and escape characters

Tags: javascript, html, string, variables, concatenation

I have this js :

```
var title = "firts title isn't working";
var html = "<input type='text' value='${title}'>";
```

I want to get this as result:

```
// "<input type='text' value='firts title isn't working'>"
```

but I get this !!!

```
// "<input type='text' value='firts title isn' t='' working=''>"
```

Comment: How are you doing the templating? Your own code or a templating engine / library?

Comment: @JoshWulf jQuery the value is an user input so I have to add it as a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not need a mix of single and double quotes, you can use doubles in the template and then the single in the text will work:

```js
var title = "firts title isn't working";
var html = `<input type="text" value="${title}">`;
document.body.innerHTML=html;
```

Otherwise HTML is HTML, and as @Barmar pointed out it has no escape characters...
... but, it has entities, and then you have both, regardless of the surrounding ones:

```js
var title = "&quot;firts&quot; title isn&apos;t working";
var html = `<input type='text' value='${title}'>`;
document.body.innerHTML=html;
```

(What is `firts`?)

And of course, you can do the replacement in code, so you can have "readable" strings, and `.replace("\'","&apos;");` them later.

Comment: "*(What is `firts`?)* misspelled **first** I would guess.

Comment: @VLAZ yes its just an example

Comment: thx sir the value is an user input I wn to generate an input with the (saved value from DB) and show it in a modal, now all works fine but when the (stored value) containe single or double quot here is when the problem occure

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys I solved it like this:

```
var title = "some data \" && \' "; // get it from user input

var chars_toEscape = {'\'':'&apos;', '\"':'&quot;', "\`":"&#96;"};
title = title.replace(/['"`]/g, char => chars_toEscape[char]);

var html = `<input type="text" value="${title}">`;

// as result input contain as value: some data " && '
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [`const`](https://www.joshwulf.com/blog/2020/02/shun-the-mutant/).

Using escaped string:

```
const title = "first title isn\\'t working";
const html = "<input type='text' value='${title}'>";
```

Use ES6 template string:

```
const title = `first title isn't working`;
const html = "<input type='text' value='${title}'>";
```

Not sure whether the second one will work for you. Depends on the templating function you are using.

You didn't show in your question how the two get combined, and that will influence what will work and what won't.

Comment: You don't need to escape single quote inside a double-quoted string.

Comment: Depends on the templating solution in use. It's not ES6 templating from the example, so I'm assuming something else is doing the templating....

Comment: If you want a literal backslash inside the string, you need `\\'`

Comment: HTML doesn't allow escaping quotes inside attribute values.

Comment: thx sir I know that but the value is an user input so I have to add it as a variable

Answer (score -3):

try this:

```js
var title = "firts title isn't working";
var html = "<input type='text' value='"+title+"'>";
alert(html);
```

Comment: The result is not valid html. _value='firts title isn'_ is followed by _t working'_. However, this last opening quote is never closed. Please adapt your answer (if it contributes something compared to the other answers) or remove it completely.